# How can this source code can create deadlock?

Tags: c++, multithreading, buffer, mutex, deadlock

The following code is a buffer for an integer. I am trying to find a possible execution of this code by multiple threads (let's say 3 threads: 1 "consumer" and 2 "producers") that leads to deadlock:

```
class OneBuf{
    Mutex m;
    CondVar cv;
    int buffer;
    bool full;

    void put (int data){
        m.lock();
        while(full) cv.wait(m);
        buffer = data;
        full = true;
        cv.signal();
        m.unlock();
    }

    int get(){
        int data;
        m.lock();
        while(!full) cv.wait(m);
        full = false;
        data = buffer;
        cv.signal();
        m.unlock();
        return data;
    }
    }
```

It's an exercise and I was asked to give an example of 3 threads (1 consumer and 2 producers) that leads to deadlock. Also, the exercise stated that if I replace the lines 12 and 22 with `cv.broadcast()` (instead of `cv.signal()`) I can avoid any deadlocks. I hope that helps.

Comment: Can't see any obvious way to deadlock this code (assuming that Mutex and CondVar are implemented as the straitforward wraps for the corresponding pthread calls). Have you seen it actually deadlocked?

Comment: @MikeTyukanov please read what I have added below the code. I hope it helps.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK, that explains something. Still I can't see how one can deadlock this code. Maybe it will help a bit if I tell what I can.

broadcast() is often needed because signal() can miss a thread, leaving it in the wait state until another signal() finally wakes it up. While technically not deadlock (sometimes it can resolve itself), this condition is better to be avoided.

Suppose full is not a bool, but an int, and it has three states: true (1), false(0) and dumpable(-1), and you have a third method dump():

```
void dump (void){
    m.lock();
    while(full!=-1) cv.wait(m);
    cerr<<buffer<<endl;
    full = 1;
    cv.signal();
    m.unlock();
}
```

and put() sets full not to 1, but to -1 (dumpable) state, so that the normal linear order of execution would be

```
buf.put(7);
buf.dump();
int val=buf.get();
```

Then suppose that multithreaded execution goes this way:

1) a thread with dump() enters, finds that full is 0, goes to wait.

2) a thread with get() enters, finds that full is 0, goes to wait.

3) a thread with put() enters, sets the value, sets full to -1, sends signal, exits unlocking mutex.

4) get() wins the race, and wakes up. Finds that value is -1 instead of 1, goes to wait again. It still unlocks the mutex, so some other put() will send signal again, and maybe now dump() will win. Or maybe not. While not a deadlock, it's bad, and may easily degenerate into something that practically would be indistinguishable from a real deadlock.

This is easily fixed by changing signal() to broadcast(). If put() sends broadcast(), then in 4) both get() and dump() are awaken. They still race, but this time they race for the mutex. get() still may win the race, but even if it does, dump() doesn't go to wait() again, it just stops until mutex is unlocked, i.e., until get() checks that full!=1 and goes to wait() unlocking the mutex. So broadcast() indeed fixes this code, and each exiting putter will find a dumper, which will eventually find a getter.

This example is contrived, almost silly, but I hope it helps to illustrate the usual problem and solution.

Returning to your code, such exit-from-wait race can happen if we get both getters and putters in the waiting pool. In that case, get() can easily wake up from a signal from another get() and go to wait again. signal will be missed, and put() which lost the race can stay in a wait state indefinitely, just like in my example.

But if the pool consists of getter or putters only, I can't see how signal() can mess up things: if the pool consists of getters, any other getter will just enter the pool, and any putter's signal will find a getter to wake up. And what I can't see is how a getter and a putter can both go into the wait state with your code. Even if, say, two putters race for the mutex while two getters wait, the winner will wake up a getter which will be guaranteed to inherit the mutex of its waker. No race between loser putter and a getter returning from wait, the returning from wait wins. Maybe I miss something.

Answer (score 0):

I think you should rather write something like:

```
try {
  mutex.acquire();
  try {
    // do something
  } finally {
    mutex.release();
  }
} catch(InterruptedException ie) {
  // ...
}
```

To answer more accurately your question, I think a deadlock can occur when the get() method is invoked first. So, the thread locks the mutex and enters an infinite loop (because the condition will never be true).

Comment: Inside the loop the call to cv.wait(m) unlocks m and suspends the thread until someone calls cv.signal(). If another thread calls another get(), it will, too, go to wait(). But if another thread calls put(), it will avoid looping, and assign buffer=value; full=true;  before put() calls signal() and unlocks the mutex to allow wait() in a getter thread be finished. So on the next check the condition will be true.